# How do I select middle part of a hyper link?

Tags: browser, browser-addons, hyperlink, selection

[image]

How do I select a middle part of an hyper-link as you see in the image above?

You can also suggest me a browser extension or a userscript that converts all links to text in a selected sub part of the page after pressing a hot-key.

(Browser: Google Chrome)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the [ToggleLink add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/togglelink-select-text-fr/pihmbjnaeenimjokcejnenhppigofjdi).

Interestingly, I just found out that pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> allows you to select part of a link with the mouse in Firefox! See if by some chance that works in Chrome as well.

Comment: Wow! This extension is even better than what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: @hkBattousai You don't even need the extension. Check out the tip about `Alt` in this answer. Unless you do this a lot and don't want to have to press the key.

Comment: That Alt tip is great! Works in Safari/Chrome on a Mac, no need for extensions. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I had the [same question](https://superuser.com/q/583795/151741), and because there wasn’t a solution for **GNU/Linux**, I asked the [question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/282336/82665).

There, [user264504 answered](https://askubuntu.com/a/442292/82665) that it’s possible by holding <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> while selecting the text with the mouse.

(As my question was about Firefox and got closed as duplicate for this one, which is about Google Chrome, I think it makes sense to also give solution for **Firefox**. There is the add-on: [Link Toggler](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/link-toggler/).)

Comment: This also works for Google Chrome on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 if it matters)

Answer (score 4):

If you click right above the link, right when the cursor changes from a hand back to a pointer, and drag across from that point, you can select the middle part of a hyperlink. I just tried it out in Chrome.

Comment: It works in Firefox (32 on Ubuntu) too but you have to be very precise - exactly on the correct pixel line.

Answer (score 4):

I know you're asking about Chrome, but Firefox allows it when you do the selection while holding the alt key pressed, so this may be worth trying with Chrome too.

Answer (score 2):

For firefox and opera <kbd>alt</kbd> + `mousedrag` as stated in other answer.

For Chrome searching text and pressing <kbd>esc</kbd>.
[image]

Here I searched for "*I save*" then press <kbd>esc</kbd> and spread the selection with arrow. Note: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> to switch between next occurance of searched text "*I save*".

Answer (score 1):

The best addon for firefox is the `drag-selected link text`. With it, you can select link text just as the normal text. Very convenient, I highly recommend it!

[image]

Comment: While someone taling holding alt key can solve the problem, but in Ubuntu gnome this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tampermonkey with this script
It allows you to disable drag and drop, and select inside the link
https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/789-select-text-inside-a-link-like-opera