# How to select (& copy) only a part of a linked text?

Tags: firefox, copy-paste, hyperlink

Let’s take this link as an example:

> [The artist John Doe shows us his cat!](http://example.com/)

I want to copy the text "John Doe" only.

Is it possible somehow?

The problem is that I can't place my cursor in the text, as then the link gets activated.

As a workaround I copy the whole text, paste it somewhere and cut out the relevant part.

Comment: As this question was closed as duplicate (although the duplicate seems to be about a solution for Google Chrome), I can’t post the solution that worked for me here. I [posted an answer](http://superuser.com/a/738255/151741) there. **tl;dr:** holding `Super`+`Alt` while selecting the text.

Answer (score 28):

To select link text in Firefox, hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> while dragging the mouse.

Note that this does not currently work in Chrome or Safari.

Comment: Don't know if this is specific to the OS, but while holding *Alt* and clicking (dragging), I move the whole window. (I'm using Ubuntu.)

Comment: That must be a global keyboard shortcut for moving windows in that window manager. The Alt-click works in Windows and Mac (with the Option key).

Comment: I see, thanks. I asked about it at [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/282336/82665).

Comment: If you're using KDE, I just ran across instructions for disabling Alt+Click here: http://superuser.com/questions/584730/how-can-i-disable-alt-mouse-default-behavior-in-kde/584752#584752

Comment: For **Ubuntu** users: Press **Win+Alt+drag**. Win+Alt is a generic shortcut for bypassing the Alt+Drag of the windows manager (useful for Wine progs too)

Answer (score 8):

If you click right above the link and drag it will select part of it. This probably works in a most browsers but I only tested it in Chrome on Windows.

Comment: I have seen users recommend this elsewhere, but this does not work for me on Chrome for Mac. Clicking anywhere above the link selects the previous line, clicking anywhere below selects the next.

Comment: Woah, didn't know that. It works, but only sometimes. Too often it selects the line from the beginning to the place where I clicked. Fiddly job.

Comment: What browser and OS are you using? It always works for me in Chrome on Windows even if I click almost a centimeter above the link.