# How can I disable 'Alt' + mouse default behavior in KDE?

Tags: kde, kwin

By default, when one holds down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drags with the mouse, it will move a window in KDE/kwin. *Is there a way to disable this for a particular application?*

I know there's a lot of application overrides (**click top left window icon** > **Advanced** > **Special Application Settings**), but I can't find one to disable this alt key. The closest I can find is to disable global keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Actually, the primary motivation for my question is now nil. I wanted to use the alt keys when running `x2go`, but I think the problem was in fact that the server wasn't using the alt+drag actions. When I switched from `gnome-desktop` to `unity` (by running `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` on the server), everything started to work as expected -- the alt keys now interact with the "guest" windows in x2go, rather than my client desktop's windowing system.

Answer (score 63):

In the KDE System Settings for Window Behavior, change the Window Actions for Inner Window, Titlebar, & Frame. With the modifier key set to Alt, set the left button to Nothing. You can also reassign the action to a different modifier key.

See also: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=109085

Comment: Is there a way to do this for individual applications? It's a useful feature generally, but some applications use alt+clicking, and it conflicts...

Comment: Just change _Alt_ key to _Meta_

Comment: In case someone is searching the setting: Start "System Settings", then look at Workspace->Window Managment->Window Behavior->Window Actions->Inner Window, Title bar & Frame, and there you can select "Nothing" for "Left butotn", "Middle button", "Right button" and "Mouse wheel" with the modifier key "Alt" (or choose an alternative modifier key).

Comment: Thanks for this! Alt + drag isn't enabled in Garuda Linux, so I was actually looking to turn it on. Turns out, Garuda changes it to Meta as its default rather than Alt, so good to know where this setting is burried!

Answer (score 4):

although Bradd's answer is correct, if you want to disable alt for just one application/window, you can go to window behaviour -> `<application>` -> appearances & fixes and check "Ignore global shortcuts" there.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it disables all global shortcuts. So, I can't for example switch between desktops with my shortcut when the particular window is active.

Answer (score 3):

There is some setting in kde, where you can choose what key should be used for the window dragging.. I switch it over to the win key - It really works well.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNeN3.png)